# Which parts of speech are 'go' and 'buy' in "I want to go buy a gift."?

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech

> I want to **go buy** a gift.

Which parts of speech are "go" and "buy"?

I am confused about this sentence.

Comment: Perhaps, it is the same as `get going` (idiomatic expression). It looks like a typo. I expect to say: go to buy, or go and buy ...

Comment: Related question: [“To go to buy” or “to go buy”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/3117/) @HermanNz you may find the discussion there interesting too.

Comment: @HermanNz Not a typo. But both are verbs. I think it's prevalent in AmE. And it's not by any means similar to *get going*.

Comment: I know that both are verbs @Man_From_India.

Comment: Look up the Quasi-Serial Verb (QSV) construction, e.g. *Constraints on Intransitive Quasi-Serial Verb Constructions in Modern Colloquial English* (Pullum 1990).  It's been given a number of other labels, such as the *go get* construction or the *go-V* construction or the double verb construction.

Answer (score 3):

I want to go buy a gift.

"to go" and "to buy" are verbs, of course. The sentence is a shortened form of "I want to go and buy a gift/present". You could also say: I want to go (in order) to buy a present.